# Ansible facts output in one line

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I need some information from Ansible facts, hence created below YAML. but its giving error. My requirement is to get the output in one line. So that we can filter it using CSV or spreadsheet.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Get content of remote server
    shell: echo system {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ crashkernel }} {{ ansible_os_family }}
```

Error:

```
+++++++++++++++++
TASK [Get content of remote server] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ip]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'crashkernel' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'status.yaml': line 5, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: Get content of remote server\n    ^ here\n"}

++++++++++++++++
```

Also tried `yamllint`:

```
$ yamllint status.yaml
status.yaml
  3:11      warning  truthy value should be one of [false, true]  (truthy)
  6:81      error    line too long (89 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crashkernel` is not a fact itself, it's a subkey of the `ansible_proc_cmdline` fact, so use

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Get content of remote server
    shell: echo system {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ ansible_proc_cmdline['crashkernel'] }} {{ ansible_os_family }}
```

Note that you can use the ansible [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) module to print messages instead of going through `echo` on the remote side:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Get content of remote server
    debug: 
      msg: "system {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ ansible_proc_cmdline['crashkernel'] }} {{ ansible_os_family }}"
```

Note also that you can use the [gather_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-gather-facts-module) module to collect facts about a host into a file containing JSON data:

> ansible localhost -m gather_facts --tree /tmp/facts

and then use your programming language of choice or a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the information you want:

> jq '.ansible_facts.ansible_proc_cmdline.crashkernel' /tmp/facts/localhost